# Parsing, Convert ifstream::get() 's int result into value

Tags: c++, parsing, syntax, ifstream

A class read a SIMPLESEM program that uses specific language and I want to check its syntax. 
For example, Infile is a opened ifstream file. Things in the file are not necessarily strings or chars, they can be command.

```
int nextChar;
nextChar = inFile.get();
```

Now nextChar is a int value, they are all 8bits, how do I convert this int result into real value and then check its syntax error? Is it something like ASCII code?

Answer (score 0):

infile::get() returns int because when an error occurs it returns EOF, to use it properly just cast to char.

```
int nextChar;
char realChar;
nextChar = inFile.get();
if(nextChar != EOF)
   realChar = static_cast<char>(nextChar);
```